# Is it any way to highlight text in <textarea>?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way to highlight text in `textarea` without backend code?

Comment: Not really. You have to use a contenteditable

Comment: ... or an overlay element over textarea.

Comment: Define "backend".

Comment: Highlight as in "make it colorful", or just select it? If you mean selecting it, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setSelectionRange is your place to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't actually highlight text in a `<textarea>`. Any markup you would add to do so would simply display as plain text within the `<textarea>`. But you can carefully craft some **CSS** and **Javascript** code to fake it:
Please check out this article [Highlight Text Inside a Textarea](https://codersblock.com/blog/highlight-text-inside-a-textarea/) for more information on how it can be crafted.